# A "foreach" issue i'm having

Tags: php

I'm having a hard time trying to figure this out, i am having a duplicate "$order_id" issue and i don't wan't the order to display if "$order_id" does not equal to the "$quantity" ordered.

So Let's say this is the order:

```
ID - ORDER_ID - QUANTITY
1900 - 1200 - 1
1901 - 1200 - 1
1902 - 1200 - 1
1903 - 1200 - 1
```

This should just foreach 1 times.

But if it would look like this:

```
ID - ORDER_ID - QUANTITY
1900 - 1200 - 4
1901 - 1200 - 4
1902 - 1200 - 4
1903 - 1200 - 4
```

This should be displayed... it might just be the mood i'm in, but i just can't seem to figure this out...

Thanks guys! ;)

---- REPLY -----

Hey,

Just updated my question, it's more of a "quantity" rather than "amount".

So for an example if i would echo this out, and the quantity is "1" but the order_id has a duplicate entry of "4" times that should just display "1" times, it should just display the same order_id, "quantity" xx times...

Not sure how i can explain further ?... don't mind the exact code, as it's just an example trying to make clear on what i'm after...

```
<?php 
foreach($coupon_details as $coupon_detail)
            {

            echo = '<td>';

        echo = 'order_id:' . $order_detail=get_single_row("orders",array("id"=>$coupon_detail->order_id)) . ;

        echo = '</td><td>';

        echo = 'quanitity:' . $order_detail=get_single_row("orders",array("id"=>$coupon_detail->quantity)) . ;

        echo = '</td><td>';

        }
    ?>
```

This example would be the MySQL table data...

So Let's say this is the order:

```
ID - ORDER_ID - QUANTITY
1900 - 1200 - 1
1901 - 1200 - 1
1902 - 1200 - 1
1903 - 1200 - 1
```

This should just foreach 1 times.

But if it would look like this:

```
ID - ORDER_ID - QUANTITY
1900 - 1200 - 4
1901 - 1200 - 4
1902 - 1200 - 4
1903 - 1200 - 4
```

---- REPLY 2 -----

Was asked for an expected output in the view file. (NOT DATABASE)

This is in the DATABASE

```
ID - ORDER_ID - QUANTITY
1900 - 1200 - 1
1901 - 1200 - 1
1902 - 1200 - 1
1903 - 1200 - 1
```

AND THIS IS HOW I WOULD LIKE IT TO ECHO FOREACH FROM DB

```
ID - ORDER_ID - QUANTITY
1900 - 1200 - 1
```

Comment: How did you come up with this?

Comment: you need to explain more what you want

Comment: Just updated, hope it's more clear now ?...

Comment: You still need to show the expected output.

Comment: Just updated again, see under "---- REPLY 2 -----"

Answer (score 0):

Try below code i made some change in your code.

```
<?php

$coupon_details = mysql_query("select * from order GROUP BY ORDER_ID AND QUANTITY");

echo "<table><tr>";
echo "<td>ID</td>";
echo "<td>ORDER_ID</td>";
echo "<td>QUANTITY</td>";
echo "</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($coupon_details))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>'.$row['id'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['ORDER_ID'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['QUANTITY'].'</td>';
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

It should work.